# what does -display UNCLAIMED mean in response to sudo lshw -c video

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 21.04

I'm having problems with my dual display since moving to 21.04

The additional drivers tab shows nothing.

I've got the correct NVIDIA driver installed.

```
sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for mark: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G84GLM [Quadro FX 1600M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f3ffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

hwinfo --gfxcard
17: PCI 100.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: VCu0.ZsCrSDGwGdA
  Parent ID: vSkL.K4GjMdJvpVB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia Quadro FX 1600M"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x040d "Quadro FX 1600M"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x019b 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Memory Range: 0xf5000000-0xf5ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xefffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xf2000000-0xf3ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xef00-0xef7f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 5 (no events)
  I/O Port: 0x00 (rw)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd0000040Dsv00001028sd0000019Bbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    XFree86 v4 Server Module: nv
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #17
```

Any ideas?

Mark

Thanks for your input

I've followed your help, and here's the result:

```
$ dkms status nvidia
nvidia, 390.143, 5.11.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
$ uname -r
5.11.0-18-generic
```

Then the log file has these lines:

```
[   102.764] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   102.806] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[   102.806] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

UPDATE

I've fixed it - I just don't know how!

Comment: It means probably that you have Secure Boor enabled. Disable it in order to allow Nvidia drivers to be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

'UNCLAIMED' means that no driver has been loaded for that card.  If you take a look at this line:

```
       configuration: latency=0
```

If it had loaded the nvidia driver, it would look like this:

```
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

How did you install the driver?  Are you sure it was installed successfully?

First, check dkms to make sure the module says it's `installed` and that it matches your current kernel; your numbers might differ from this example:

```bsh
$ dkms status nvidia
nvidia, 465.19.01, 5.4.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
$ uname -r
5.4.0-74-generic
```

If that's correct, check the log file at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and read through it, looking for any lines that contain `NVIDIA` or `(EE)` to see if the driver encountered any errors that might provide a clue as to what is going wrong.